# Java Moving a Value to the end of an Array

Tags: java, arrays

The code is below, I am interested as to what every single line in this code does. I will write what I think it does and please tell me if I am write. The method takes in an int array and an integer named index, if that index is greater than 0 and less than the array length, set the value of that index to the number v. Looping through the array, i starting with the place of the index you'd like to bring to the end until the end of the array, if it is in last place then set the index value to v. Otherwise make the index value increment 1. I don't really understand the i, index, please help.

Comment: Can you please put the code inline in your question instead of as an image.

Comment: You need the code as text in the question, not as an image

Comment: what have you done more to understand? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

firstly, as others have pointed out, it would be better to include the code directly in your question instead of as an image.

Anyway, your interpretation of the first part of the code (checking the value of the index and setting it to v) is basically correct. However, the next part isn't quite right. The part about setting the value at the last place of the array to v is correct. But it is not correct to say that if i is not the array length, then increment the index value by 1. The statement `arr[i] = arr[i+1]` does not increment the index value. It takes the value of the array at the *next* index, and sets the value at the *current* index to be that value.

For example, if you had an array `[2,3,6,7]`, and i is currently 2, then the value at index 2 (which is 6) will be set to the value at index 3 (that is, 7). Thus, the array would become `[2,3,7,7]`. Hope this isn't too confusing.